# Networkx set complex node attribute

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to individually update nodes for a certain new custom attribute called 'journeys', but am having severe difficulties with it.

Say I have some graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

cols = ['node_a','node_b','travel_time','attribute']

data = [['A','B',3,'attribute1'],
        ['B','C',1,'attribute1'],
        [ 'C','D',7,'attribute1'],
         ['D','E',3,'attribute1'],
         ['E','F',2,'attribute1'],
         ['F','G',4,'attribute1'],
         ['A','L',4,'attribute2'],
         ['L','D',3,'attribute2']
         ]
edges = pd.DataFrame(data)
edges.columns = cols
G=nx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist(edges,'node_a','node_b', ['travel_time','attribute'])
```

For each node, I want to add an attribute in the form of `{direction: [[id,timestamp, set_of_carrying_items]]}` where the inner one is a list of lists as i want to add more lists of the form `[id,timestamp, carrying_items]` to it.

Example: Update a particular node A with

```
 new_attribute = {'A':{'up': [[0, Timestamp('1900-01-01 05:31:00'), set()]]}}}
```

However, no matter what I try, the node doesnt get updated correctly. `nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'A')` returns an empty dictionary. But `nx.get_node_attributes(G,'up')` returns the attribute!!

It seems i'm setting it wrongly but I cant figure out how. Anyone know the proper way?

Using networkx 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

`nx.get_node_attributes(G,X)` returns attributes called X for all nodes. You're looking for `G.node['nodeA']`

if your attribute is of the form `{'nodeA':{'attribute_name': value}}`, you'll set `value` to `attribute_name` for node `nodeA`.

For example, in my case:

```
att = {'nodeA':{'up': [[1, Timestamp('1900-01-01 22:31:00'), set()]]}}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G,att)
```

works